Massive download of files with authentication from Google Drive
I have thousands of files in a shared folder in Google Drive which I do not have full control. I need to download them to a server with enough memory and CPUs for analysis.


Access to https://script.new/ and log in to Google. By this, the
authentication issue is addressed.
Click on the 'plus' button next to 'Libraries' on the left of the
screen. Enter the script ID
1HLv6tWz0oXFOJHerBTP8HsNmhpRqssijJatC92bv9Ym6HSN69_UuzcDk and
proceed to install the library BatchRequest.
Click on the 'plus' button next to the 'Services' on the left of the
screen. Choose 'Drive API' and proceed to enable the Drive API
services. v3 was adopted in my case.
Copy the following snippet to your script. The only thing you'll
have to input is your folder ID which is the suffix of the link to
your folder in which there are files to be downloaded.

function myFunction() {
  const sourceFolderId = "18b0tVyn4ErDfduhaMQi4vZSOCYAqB2tl";  // Please set the source folder ID.

  const getFiles = (id, res = []) => {
    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
    const files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      const file = files.next();
      res.push({name: file.getName(), id: file.getId()})
    }
    let ids = [];
    const folders = folder.getFolders();
    while (folders.hasNext()) ids.push(folders.next().getId());
    if (ids.length > 0) ids.forEach(id => getFiles(id, res));
    return res;
  }

  const files = getFiles(sourceFolderId);

  // Create a text file
  const fileIdsText = files.map(file => file.id).join("\n");
  const txtFile = DriveApp.createFile('file_ids.txt', fileIdsText);
  console.log('File IDs saved to: ' + txtFile.getUrl());
}


After execution, you may find a message in the log saying that your
file IDs are stored in file_ids.txt in your own Google Drive, in
which each line contains one file ID corresponding to one file in
your targetted folder.
For Linux users, install gdown and proceed with the following shell script to download by referring to the file IDs:


#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r file_id
do
    download_url="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=${file_id}"
    gdown "$download_url"
done < ids.txt

echo "File download completed."


This solution might fail due to the  Apps Script time execution límit for the account running it

Do you have any recommendations for an alternative solution?

There are already several questions here about this. You should start by improving the question to include details, like why you can't use or are looking for code-based alternatives to Google Drive for Desktop. If this solution can handle thousands of files, provide details about the successful execution, like the type of account used (consumer/gmail.com or Workspace) to run the Google Apps Script, as the quota varies depending on the account type.
